# Using existing business logic in a webservice

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, asmx

I have a very simple method GetMembers() in a class MemberCollection which inherits from list, this method returns a list of members straight from the selected database and currently sits in a class library.

I would like to have a webservice which will sit on the live server and can utilise this business logic class library which calls this existing method and returns me a MemberCollection object which I can then use on a winforms application.

I am currently struggling to make this work as it seems to be returning an array of the member object (member[]) rather than the actual MemberCollection object and all the types are wrong.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the case of SOAP webservices Lists will be converted to arrays while they are returned from the service. You can write a wrapper instead to convert them to lists.
Or you can use a WCF where you configure it to return System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: Are you able to provide an examplee of this, I was hoping to use the same BL on both sides so it's easy to work with the object and keeps the code maintainable or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: pls refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171457/how-to-config-webservice-to-return-arraylist-instead-of-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525463/why-does-my-wcf-service-return-and-array-instead-of-a-list-t threads.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use the **CollectionDataContract** attribute on the MemberCollection class definition. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFCollectionTypeSharing.aspx) for more info.

Also - your classes need to be serializable. You may need to remove the data access code from the class in order to send it over the wire.